# How to run Clipper Application

Tags: clipper

I have a legacy code base written in CLIPPER. I don't have any idea of CLIPPER programming language. 
How do I get started with it and deploy this application? Is it a scripting language OR some sort of OOPS language any study reference will be helpful

Thanks in Advance

Kaushik

Answer (score 3):

[Clipper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipper_%28programming_language%29) is 16-bit compiler for character-based (not GUI) applications running on MS-DOS platform. There are, however, 3rd-party tools that will allow to produce 16-bit Windows GUI applications.

It's still owned by Computer Associates but all future development and support was delegated to [GrafX](http://www.grafxsoft.com/clipper.htm) long time ago.

The last released version was 5.3 but many developers stayed with 5.2e. The last update was around Y2K.

There are [Harbour](http://harbour.github.io/) and [xHarbour](http://www.xharbour.org/) open source projects that developed their own compilers for this language (which in the beginning was similar to dBase III).

You can find information about the language and some 3-rd party libs in a Clipper section of [this web-site](http://www.ousob.com/ng/).

Native Clipper compiles all its code into a single executable that runs on user desktops. Its data and index files are usually placed on a network share. Executable itself can also be placed on a share with user desktops having a short-cut to it.

Native Clipper applications (16-bit) will not run under 64-bit Windows. There are emulators (like [DosBox](http://www.dosbox.com/)) that allow to overcome such limitation.

Clipper related questions can be asked on [`comp.lang.clipper` newsgroup](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.lang.clipper).

If you have more questions add them as comments here.

Answer (score 0):

Another good resource is Norton Guides for Windows, you can download it from a great site with lot of information about Clipper:
[Download NGW](http://www.the-oasis.net/files/utils/ngw110.zip) from www.the-oasis.net.

I was unable to find the .NG files on that site, but you can see them online [here](http://www.ousob.com/norton.php) if you want or try to found the files googling them.